# How can I run external programs using Perl 6? (e.g. like "system" in Perl 5)

Tags: perl, raku

I can use `system` in Perl 5 to run external programs. I like to think of `system` like a miniature "Linux command line" inside Perl. However, I cannot find documentation for `system` in Perl 6. What is the equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to using [`shell`](http://doc.perl6.org/type/IO#sub_shell) or [`run`](http://doc.perl6.org/type/IO#sub_run), which replace [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) from Perl 5, you can also use [`NativeCall`](http://doc.perl6.org/language/nativecall) to invoke the libc `system` function.

On my Windows box, it looks like this:

```
use NativeCall;
sub system(Str --> int32) is native("msvcr110.dll") { * };
system("echo 42");
```

Comment: Is that `system` basically the same as the Perl 5 version?

Comment: If you have to specify `"msvcr110.dll"`, I presume it's not terribly portable. Can you pass it multiple arguments, like Perl 5's `system("echo" "42")`? (I know Windows doesn't do command line argument processing the same way Unix does.)

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms: no, it's the one from the C standard library; to get the Perl5 one, you'd need [Inline::Perl5](https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5)

Comment: @KeithThompson: no, `system` expects a single argument - on Windows, you'd need a function of the [`_exec` family](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/431x4c1w.aspx) to avoid processing

Comment: I was looking for `shell` and `run`, but mentioning `NativeCall` adds another dimension to interacting with the Operating System that I'd not considered. Therefore, I'm marking this as the accepted answer. I still recommend readers also see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547490/how-can-i-use-the-command-line-or-what-is-the-equivalent-of-system-in-perl/29547491#29547491) for a quick `shell` and `run` overview and example.

Answer (score 9):

Perl6 actually has two commands that replace [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) from Perl 5.

In Perl6, [`shell`](http://doc.perl6.org/type/IO#sub_shell) passes its argument to the shell, similar to Perl 5's `system` when it has one argument that contains metacharacters.

In Perl6, [`run`](http://doc.perl6.org/type/IO#sub_run) tries to avoid using the shell. It takes its first argument as a command and the remaining arguments as arguments to that command, similar to Perl 5's `system` when it has multiple arguments.

For example:

```
shell('ls > file.log.txt');   # Capture output from ls (shell does all the parsing, etc)

run('ls','-l','-r','-t');     # Run ls with -l, -r, and -t flags
run('ls','-lrt');             # Ditto
```

See also this [2014 Perl 6 Advent post on "running external programs"](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2014/12/06/day-06-running-external-programs-from-perl-6).