# How do I create a symbolic link in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

How do I create a symbolic link using Perl 6?

Of course, [as mentioned in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547490/how-can-i-use-the-command-line-or-what-is-the-equivalent-of-system-in-perl), I can use actual shell commands using `shell` or `run`:

```
shell('ln -s REALLY_LONG_FASTQ_NAME.fastq short.fq');
run('ln', '-s', 'REALLY_LONG_FASTQ_NAME.fastq', 'short.fq');
```

But, I'd prefer to be able to create them more directly with a function.

Comment: btw: edited after downvotes. It is now more concise and focused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### UPDATED

---

```
symlink("original_filename","link_filename");
```

See also the [official documentation on symlink](http://docs.perl6.org/routine/symlink).