# How do I store the value returned by either run or shell?

Tags: raku

Let's say I have this script:

```
# prog.raku
my $info = run "uname";
```

When I run `prog.raku`, I get:

```
$ raku prog.raku
Linux
```

Is there a way to store a stringified version of the returned value and prevent it from being output to the terminal?

There's already a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547490/how-can-i-run-external-programs-using-perl-6-e-g-like-system-in-perl-5/29547491#29547491) but it doesn't provide a specific answer.

Comment: you could also use a [shell quote](https://docs.perl6.org/language/quoting#Shell_quoting:_qx) `qx{uname}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to enable the stdout pipe, which otherwise defaults to `$*OUT`, by setting `:out`. So:

```
my $proc = run("uname", :out);
my $stdout = $proc.out;
say $stdout.slurp;
$stdout.close;
```

which can be shortened to:

```
my $proc = run("uname", :out);
say $proc.out.slurp(:close);
```

If you want to capture output on stderr separately than stdout you can do:

```
my $proc = run("uname", :out, :err);
say "[stdout] " ~ $proc.out.slurp(:close);
say "[stderr] " ~ $proc.err.slurp(:close);
```

or if you want to capture stdout and stderr to one pipe, then:

```
my $proc = run("uname", :merge);
say "[stdout and stderr] " ~ $proc.out.slurp(:close);
```

Finally, if you don't want to capture the output and don't want it output to the terminal:

```
my $proc = run("uname", :!out, :!err);
exit( $proc.exitcode );
```

Answer (score 5):

By default `run` just passes the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to the parent process's `STDOUT` and `STDERR`.

You have to tell it to do something else.

The simplest is to just give it `:out` to tell it to keep `STDOUT`. (Short for `:out(True)`)

```perl6
my $proc = run 'uname', :out;
my $result = $proc.out.slurp(:close);
```

```perl6
my $proc = run 'uname', :out;
for $proc.out.lines(:close) {
  .say;
}
```

You can also effectively tell it to just send `STDOUT` to `/dev/null` with `:!out`. (Short for `:out(False)`)

---

There are more things you can do with `:out`

```perl6
{
  my $file will leave {.close} = open :w, 'test.out';
  run 'uname', :out($file); # write directly to a file
}

print slurp 'test.out'; # Linux
```

```perl6
my $proc = run 'uname', :out;

react {
  whenever $proc.out.Supply {
    .print

    LAST {
      $proc.out.close;
      done; # in case there are other whenevers
    }
  }
}
```

If you are going to do that last one, it is probably better to use Proc::Async.

Answer (score 4):

The solution covered in this answer is concise.

This sometimes outweighs its disadvantages:

- Doesn't store the result code. If you need that, use ugexe's solution instead.
- Doesn't store output to stderr. If you need that, use ugexe's solution instead.
- Potential vulnerability. This is explained below. Consider ugexe's solution instead.

---

Documentation of the features explained below starts with [the quote adverb `:exec`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/quoting#index-entry-%3Aexec_%28quoting_adverb%29).

## Safest unsafe variant: `q`

The safest variant uses a single `q`:

```
say qx[ echo 42 ] # 42
```

If there's an error then the construct returns an empty string and any error message will appear on stderr.

This safest variant is analogous to a **single** quoted string like `'foo'` passed to the shell. Single quoted strings don't [interpolate](https://docs.perl6.org/language/glossary#index-entry-Variable_Interpolation) so there's no vulnerability to a [code injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).

That said, you're passing a single string to the shell which may not be the shell you're expecting so it may not parse the string as you're expecting.

## Least safe unsafe variant: `qq`

The following line produces the same result as the `q` line but uses the least safe variant:

```
say qqx[ echo 42 ]
```

This double `q` variant is analogous to a double quoted string (`"foo"`). This form of string quoting *does* interpolate which means it is subject to a [code injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) if you include a variable in the string passed to the shell.